# Backgrid.filter precedence of filtering based on field name

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, filter, backgrid, lunrjs

I am new to backgrid.js and I am using filter as an extension function for my web app. I am quite confused about `LunrFilter`. As the code defines in [this page](http://backgridjs.com/ref/extensions/filter.html#lunrfilter), it has the parameter `{ field : 10 }`. May I know what and how does field name and boost value affect the filtration of collection?

Also, is it possible for Backgrid.filter to filter collections by precedence?

For example, I have the following data:

```
Record #1 - fname : Adam; lname : Smith
Record #2 - fname : Luke; lname : Adam
Record #3 - fname : John; lname : Adam
```

I would like to take precedence of `lname` over `fname` on filtering.
If I key in "Adam" on search bar - table must display Records #2 and #3 first, and #1 last.

Answer (score 0):

from the doc

> An optional boost param can be passed to affect how much tokens in this field rank in search results, by default the boost value is 1.

i suspect it is used to rank the seach result. 
the fields actually should be a json object. where each name is the field name. and each value is the boost value.

```
fields:{
    Name:10,
    Field2:1,
    Field3:1,
}
```

Be default the boost is 1 in lunrjs and is optional. But I guess in this case you have to set boost for each field.